# How to solve the circular import problem in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

I got the 2 following python files:

1: debug.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from helper import show_msg

root = Tk()
root.geometry('900x500')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("test")

menu = ["elem1", "elem2"]
menu1 = ttk.Combobox(root, state="readonly",values=["choose"] + menu, width=55)
menu1.current(0)
menu1.pack()
menu1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", show_msg(menu1))

debug_frame = tk.Frame(root)
debug_frame.pack()
debug_bar = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(debug_frame, width=100, height=5)
debug_bar.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

2: helper.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from debug import debug_bar

def print_msg_on_screen(msg):
    debug_bar.insert(tk.INSERT, msg)
    print(msg)

def show_msg(menu1):
    if(menu1.current() == 0):
        msg="choose an element"
        print_msg_on_screen(msg)
    if (menu1.current() == 1):
        msg = "you chose element1"
        print_msg_on_screen(msg)
    if (menu1.current() == 2):
        msg = "you chose element2"
        print_msg_on_screen(msg)
```

I wanna print whatever msg I get from show_msg from helper.py into the debug bar (in tkinter) that I declared in debug.py, but I keep getting this error :

ImportError: cannot import name 'show_msg' from partially initialized module 'helper' (most likely due to a circular import)

Is there a way to make this circular import work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is better to pass `debug_bar` to `show_msg()` as well, so no need to import `debug` inside `helper.py`.

Comment: @acw1668 it didn't work.. it doesn't print anything in the `debug_bar`

Comment: Did you try my answer? It works for me.

Comment: @acw1668 yeah I just tried it and it works! I'm trying to apply it to the actual code though, and so far it isn't working.. I'm trying to figure out where the problem is..

Answer (score 1):

It is better to pass `debug_bar` to `show_msg()` (which in turn passes to `print_msg_on_screen()`), so no need to import `debug` inside `helper.py`:

###### debug.py

```py
...
# lambda should be used instead of direct calling show_msg()
menu1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lambda e: show_msg(menu1, debug_bar))
...
```

###### helper.py

```py
import tkinter as tk

def print_msg_on_screen(msg, widget):
    widget.insert(tk.INSERT, msg+'\n')
    print(msg)

def show_msg(menu1, widget):
    print(f'{menu1}')
    if(menu1.current() == 0):
        msg="choose an element"
        print_msg_on_screen(msg, widget)
    if (menu1.current() == 1):
        msg = "you chose element1"
        print_msg_on_screen(msg, widget)
    if (menu1.current() == 2):
        msg = "you chose element2"
        print_msg_on_screen(msg, widget)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `show_msg` before `debug_bar` is defined (`show_msg` references `print_msg_on_screen`, which references `debug_bar`).

If you're not using `show_msg` and `print_msg_on_screen` anywhere else, I would move these both into `debug.py`, and order it like this:

```py
def print_msg_on_screen(msg):
    ...

def show_msg(menu1):
    ...

debug_bar = ...

menu1.bind(..., show_msg(menu1))
```

Comment: in the given example it would work, however in the actual code it's gonna be very hard to move the functions. I also tried to define the debug_bar before the calling of the function and didn't work..

Comment: That was just to solve an error that you were going to get after you resolve the circular import. There isn't any other way to solve the circular import other than moving the functions / their usage. Just a part of project structure.